# Format text from a character or word to the end of the line

Tags: vba, ms-word

The code below finds the text "//" and formats the entire line with green color.

I'm trying to modify it so that it's only formatted from the text "//" to the end of the line. (including "//")

So instead of this result:

**example text //color changed**

I aim to achieve this:

example text **//color changed**

```
Sub FindWord_and_ChangeColor()

    Dim LastRow, i As Long
    
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Text = "//"
        .Execute
    End With
    
    Do While Selection.Find.Found
        Selection.Expand Unit:=wdSentence
        Selection.Font.Color = RGB(107, 187, 117)
        Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Selection.Find.Execute
    Loop
End Sub
```

I'm recording macros to see if I can find a solution in the auto-generated code. But I thank in advance to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`Selection.Expand Unit:=wdSentence`

to

`Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdSentence, Count:=1`

Comment: Wow! worked perfectly!
thank you very much for this tip. One more thing I learn to use in VBA